# Why group by and sum aren't removing dup values in rows

Tags: sql, netezza

We're using Netezza SQL.
I have three fields Customer, Account, and Revenue.

I'm summing the Revenue like so.

```
Select Customer, Sum(Revenue) REV_TOT
from Cust_REV
group by ACCOUNT;
```

Assuming there is more than one ACCOUNT PER CUST.

```
**CUSTOMER  REV_TOT**
15411780    0.5700
15411780    0.0000
15411790    65.1910
15411790    0.0000
15411790    21.4960
15411790    28.0180
```

Notice the CUSTOMER NUMBER Doesn't condense. Shouldn't it? What do I need to do?

Comment: Your not grouping by Customer, your grouping by Account.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
Select Customer, Sum(Revenue) REV_TOT
from Cust_REV
group by Customer,ACCOUNT;
```